# I am trying to obtain the lenght of all the formals in r functions in order to know which.max in the list created. I am a Psychologist not a programer

Tags: r, list, for-loop

This is the code for creating the list:

```
objs <- mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)
funs <- Filter(is.function, objs)
```

I have tried this:

```
form_list <- for(i in names(funs)) {
        formals(i)
}
```

It produces an empty object. Then I have tried

```
form_list <- sapply(names(funs), formals)
longer_args <- sapply(form_list, length)
longest_args <- which.max(longer_args)
long_funct <- funs[961]
```

evaluates:

```
$scan
funs_elem <- length(formals(scan))

 funs_elem
[1] 22
```

It is there a shorter way to the answer? Excuse my English.

Comment: Maybe you want: `max(sapply(Filter(is.function, mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)), function(i) length(formals(i))))`

Comment: Very nice, and in one line of code. Thaks a lot.